# what is the time complexity (big O) of a recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Does a recursive function have a time complexity of it's own.
Like the the time complexity of a `for` loop which is looping 'n' time is Big O(n).
Similarly does a recursive function have a fixed time complexity or does it depend on the problem.

Comment: Depends on what you're recursing.

Comment: Note that constructs like `for` (and concepts like recursion) don't have complexities; it depends on what you do with them. Algorithms have complexities, and `for`s and recursion may be used in algorithms. It perfectly possible to write an algorithm using a `for` loop that runs with a complexity other than O(n), and the complexity of a recursive algorithm will depend on the exact algorithm.

Comment: You can loop over n times with recursion and it is big O(n) as well. You can make other big O like O(n^2) with both recursion and for loops. Potato potato!

Answer (score 2):

In addition, recursive function like this:

```
func linear(n):
    return (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * linear(n-1)
```

Has complexity O(n).

But after this example

```
func exponential(n):
    if n <= 1: return 1
    exponential(n-1)
    exponential(n-1)
```

You can think it degrades 2n, although real complexity is O(2^n)

---

[This graph image would make more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7FgJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). It helps determine the time complexity of a recursive function.